# Реализация ITSG-06

Tags: c++, windows, ос

Появилась необходимость реализовать [ITSG-06](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-the-csec-itsg-06-method-2625833) на C++. Вопрос в том, хватит ли мне циклической перезаписи файла, в соответствии с алгоритмом, через его хэндл (для Win), а потом простого удаления? Или нужно побайтово используя [FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTER_BASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405526(v=vs.85).aspx)  переписать память отведённую под файл? Или эти методы равносильны?

Comment: Хватит циклической перезаписи. FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTER_BASE  - вернёт вам начальный кластер, что позволит вам удалить (если есть админские права и прямой доступ к HDD) первый кластер (4096 байт как правило) а дальше...? А дальше вам нужно искать как поднять всю цепочку кластеров, поэтому первое - проще.

Comment: @nick_n_a будет ли как таковая разница в результате если использовать указатель на файл вместо хэндла?

Comment: Что вы называете "указатель на файл"? Стартовый сектор? Или указатель File-Position который закреплён за хандлом? Или указатель-ссылка на хандл?

Comment: Если стартовый сектор, то в первом комментарии я уже ответил. Файл может быть разбросан по всему диску. И зная начальный кластер или сектор, можно уничтожить только первый блок файла. И то, как вам "уплотнение" файлов (возможность записи в кластер двух файлов), или есть ещё прикол - хранение файла в MFT?

Comment: Вы можете попробовать через FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS получить список кластеров. Но имейте ввиду, что NTFS любит хранить мелкие файлы не в кластерах, а в самой MFT. Т.е. бывают случаи когда файл хранится вне кластера. Есть ли функции позволяющие узнать где записан файл с точностью до байтов - не знаю.